# StackOverflowError when instantiating an object in another class

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Testing.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     TestList t = new TestList();
}
```

TestList.java

```
public class TestList extends ArrayList<Test> {

     protected TestList tList;

     public TestList() {
          tList = new TestList();
     }
}
```

I also have a Test.java class that works fine. The issue is in the main method, when the TestList t object is instantiated, I get a StackOverflow Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

I'm not sure HOW to fix this because the object has to be a TestList.

Comment: You are recursively calling `TestList` constructor with any termination condition.

Comment: You get the error because in your constructor you basically call the same constructor. Why do you need that field? How would you use it in your code?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question after receiving answers.

Answer (score 3):

java.lang.StackOverflowError means that the stack has been burst.
You have a recursive call, without a stop condition.
I think in your method `public TestList()`, you want something like this `tList = new ArrayList<Test>`;

Comment: it's because the type in `protected TestList tList;`. Most likely shoud be `protected ArrayList<Test>  tList;`

Comment: You already have that in the main function The TestList is that object that are you trying to build. Another instances will instantiate that.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems as if you are creating an element of itself within its constructor.  This will result in it infinitely creating instances of itself.

When you call new TestList() it then calls new TestList() which then calls new TestList() and on and on until you receive the stack overflow error.

If you need to have an object have an instance of itself I would look into using a singleton.  Although, based on this being a list I am not sure that is what is best suited to solve your problem.  Can you shed a little more light on exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: If I were you I would eliminate the tList from the TestList object.  I would then reference the list as "this" when needing to reference the list from within itself. From the code you have shown though I see no reason that you would need to extend the base functions of ArrayList.  Can you describe more exactly what you are trying to do?